# About iOS IPv6 network with ionic framework

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, networking, ionic-framework

Yesterday, I submit my app for review, but I got a message from apple.

> Apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required.
>
> For additional information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please refer to [Supporting iPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1%E2%80%9D).
>
> For a networking overview, see [About Networking](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html).

My app is used ionic framework, how can I fix this problem.

I already used domain to access my server, but this problem still exist.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I used this plugin [cordova-HTTP](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP)

the last version this used the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) v3.1.0

then, add some code to solving my networking issue

```
// using AFNetworking if on iOS device
if ($window.cordova && ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
    // $window.CordovaHttpPlugin.get
    // $window.CordovaHttpPlugin.post
    // or
    // cordovaHTTP.get
    // cordovaHTTP.post
} else {
    // $http.get
    // $http.post
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, so did you confirm your normal $http.post which worked for you on IPV4 on iOS didn't work for apple's test environment ? I'm facing the same issue and if you could provide with more details , it would be great. Thanks in advance .

Comment: @Tobio: using NAT64 to simulate an IPv6 only WiFi connection for our iOS device, our app was working fine, but Apple still rejected it. After using `cordova-http` instead of straight `$http`, we had no more IPv6 issues. I'm not sure though why the request from UIWebView doesn't work though (maybe with WKWebView it will?).

Comment: @user276648 My app was working fine on NAT64 as well, but it didn't work in the Apple review environment. They kept rejecting and after few days they themselves approved the app. I wonder whether if it was some issue on their side.

Comment: @Tobio: so you just kept republishing your app without modifying your app nor your backend, and eventually they approved it? If so it indeed sounds like something is weird on their side - or they didn't want to be bothered by you anymore ;)

Comment: @user276648 You can be right in both the statements, the funny thing was once they stopped responding to my requests for further testing, I worked on a build to embed a real-time log and I published it to TestFlight for testing. Moments before I was to send for review, my earlier build got approved by them. Weird  indeed.

Comment: Hey guys, I'm also with you all. Same issue. So, the only way is to go to cordova-Http plugin?

Comment: this solution is quite hard to include for large projects with hundred of $http calls. Do you think $resource is impacted as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem too (kind of) but I didnt know that was only happening in iOS10, in fact the app was working in iOS 9.2 and under (real device and simulator). I discover this issue submitting the app to AppStore (just the same as a week before, and this one was approved). They just rejected the app because of "The app is not supporting IPv6 connections"...it was great :____D , we changed all the server side, not literal IP use, at the end, we leave the server ready to support IPv6 and passing all the tests. We submitted again the app... and...they just rejected the app because of "The app is not supporting IPv6 connections". It was unbelievable...

Finally in an act of despair and after 100 absurd tests and even having read some similar cases of rejection I just did an update of my simulator version, in order to use the app under other version of iOS. I was realized that the problem was only for iOS 10+. And here is the problem: after June 16, Apple have changed their policies and they only support now IPv6 connections, despite that everybody says that you should update the meta tag  "Content-Security-Policy" after that change, it's not true, at least in my case. Finally **I only could compile and test the app normally (in iOS10) without this meta tag**.

PD. Yesterday I have submitted a change in my app, Apple rejected the app again because the IPv6 connections issue...Then, I changed my version, I compiled the app again...without a single change in the code and then I have submitted again to AppStore...and "voila"...they have accepted the same app rejected before...

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**No need to make changes in your app code.**

**You have to check on API server have to support IPv6 Network.**

Please find details -- http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/blog/2016/05/starting-june-1-apple-requires-all-ios-apps-to-work-in-ipv6-only-networks/?gclid=CK6K9ZfWgNMCFUoXaAodkuoGhw

Answer (score 0):

If your app should connect to a backend server/API, you should test if is working in IPV6 mode, we had that issue. Update your server network configuration and DNS rules, then you can use a tool like this for ping tests
https://centralops.net/co/Ping.aspx

Answer (score -1):

From my experience.
I had that same problem. I used https://ready.chair6.net/ to check if my backend supports ipv6. After DevOps added support ipv6 to the server,  Apple accepted my app.