# Apple rejected our phonegap app for not having ipv6 support

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, ipv6, appstore-approval

We submitted cordova phonegap app to apple and it was rejected saying that our app does not support ipv6. This is the first time we are getting this error and not sure on exact steps for fixing this issue.

Our app is using amazon ec2 and we noticed that amazon ec2 is not supporting ipv6. So we want to know where do we need to fix this? In the amazon or inside the app?

If it is amazon, how we can fix it? we tried to fix amazon issue by adding ELB but it has not solved the problem yet.

We are using latest version of cordova and all libraries are latest version. Please let us know

Comment: do you have hardcoded IPs on your app?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37896631/276648 where the use of `cordova-http` fixes the IPv6 issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue related to your webservice/webserver.

Since this June, Apple expects Apps to run on IPV6 networks. Apple has started rejecting Apps which do no comply with this.

NSURLSession, NSURLConnection, AFNetworking 3.x+ all support IPV6

If you are using any other network libraries, please use below link to test IPV6 support 
http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/

If you come across issues in making web requests when your App is running on an IPV6 network, you will have to update/replace your networking libraries to IPV6 supporting equivalents.

Once you are done testing your App with IPV6 support, you can re-submit it to the app store for approval.

Comment: I believe whatever libraries you have mentioned is native libraries but we are developing hybrid app using cordova plugin.

Comment: Yes. But the  reason for the issue is the same. Just update the networking libraries to IPV6 supported versions.

Comment: We updated network libraries to the latest version but Apple rejected the App again.. we are not sure what else need to check

Comment: After updating the network libraries, did you check if network request were able to go through with your App on an IPV6 network? You need to check to be sure its working fine on IPV6. Follow this link to host an IPV6 network on your mac http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/

Comment: We had tested this.. it was not working in initial testing but started working after sometime.. we did not do any change.. so it was strange..

is there any other particular libraries, functions we need to avoid in phonegap to make it ipv6 compatible

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693256/required-ipv6-compatibility-ios-app-rejected-by-apple