# Cordova phonegap app IPV6 compatibility

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Our app developed in Cordova has been rejected by Apple multiple times for being non-compatible with IPV6 only network. We had followed instructions in the below link from Apple and our app was working fine... but it still get rejected by Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1

We had upgraded cordova, network libraries to latest version before submitting. Now we have reached a situation where we are not sure how to proceed.

I am seeing different links in stackoverflow related to native development but I am unable to find any solutions that explains how to fix this in a cordova-phonegap environment.

Looking forward to your inputs.

Comment: we used the same test scenario and got rejected the 2nd time, too. 
The only component in our app, where I'm not shure how it makes web calls, is Google Analytics. So, today we try to remove GA and upload for review again.

Comment: We submitted again got rejected for some other issue.. Seems like we are able to fix the ipv6 issue..will share more details soon

Comment: oh yes, please share your details. Today we submitted also again and now we are waiting for review.

Comment: UPDATE: out app got rejected the 3rd time for IPV6 reasons. We wrote several comments in the reiview tickets, but get no answer. Each time the same rejection message.

Comment: Next Update: I think I found our problem. It has nothing to do with IPV6 incompatibility. We support 2 languages (german and french) and the Apple tester have english language settings on their devices. That was the reason, that our app was crashing during the app review, because german was not the default for all unhandled languages. 
I hope the app is now ok for apple.

Comment: @user3514328 please post as an answer what you did to fix the IPv6 issue.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37896631/276648 where the use of `cordova-http` fixes the IPv6 issue. Google Analytics shouldn't really impact the rejection, as even if the analytics doesn't work, the app itself should work.